# What is "ipx" in tcl?

Tags: xilinx, vivado, tcl

I have a theoretical question regarding *tcl* commands, specifically *ipx*.

I am working with a project which contains several IPs. Each IP has a corresponding *tcl* file which is used to package such IP to include it in the IP catalog. Studying the code, I encountered with several *tcl* commands that I have found easily in the corresponding user guide (UG835). Nonetheless, there are some other commands that begin with `ipx::` (e.g. `ipx::package_project`).

I have looked for information regarding *ipx* and I haven't found anything that helps me understand what it exactly is. The little I have found indicates that it is an IP integrator, but I haven't found neither a formal definition nor an explanation of how it's used. Also, I haven't found any user guide that contains a detailed explanation about these *ipx* commands (`ipx::package_project`, `ipx::add_subcore`).

Does anybody know what *ipx* exactly is, why it is used (I'm guessing for package integration) and where can I find information about its commands?

Comment: `ipx` is not a command of TCL itself, but something Vivado's TCL libraries has, just in case that help un-confuse you about documentation.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ok, but things like `package_project` or `add_subcore` (in `ipx::package_project` and `ipx::add_subcore`, respectively) are commands, aren't they? The double colon looks like the resolution operator used in *C++* but I don't know if it serves the same purpose as I haven't found any information in that regard.

Comment: That means `ipx` is a Tcl _namespace_ and `package_project` is a procedure defined within that namespace. You might find this chapter of the Tcl tutorial helpful: http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl31.html